# TI-99/4a RF modulator, fuzzy video

Tags: video, ti-99

I recently purchased a TI-99/4a.  Well, 2 actually.  Both work, but I only have one RF modulator.  I ordered a composite adapter, but that hasn't arrived yet.  Both work on the RF modulator, but the video output is very poor.  The audio seems to be working perfectly.  It looks like it can be opened, but I don't want to damage it to find out nothing can repaired, as it is in a nice condition.  Are there any capacitors in the RF modulator or anything else that can be serviced?

Comment: Typically an RF modulator would have settings for different channels - e.g., channel 3 or channel 4. Things have changed a bit with digital TV, but still worth trying any different settings available, if you have not already done so.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: Many RF modulators had an adjustable tuning coil which could be calibrated and then a switch that would load the oscillator circuit by a non-adjustable amount.  A modulator that was calibrated to be perfectly in tune for one channel would thus often be less well in tune for the other.

Comment: I switched from channel 3 to channel 4.  It is a massive improvement.  However, its still a bit fuzzy.  I guess I will wait till the composite adapter comes in to see how much better it can be.  Once I confirms the composite cable works, then I will open up the RF modulator to see if there are any potential adjustments or hardware replacements.

Comment: Are you using an old analog monitor, or are you going through an analog-to-digital converter to a digital monitor?

Comment: @JonCuster its a "modern" analog 4:3 LCD TV.  It has no digital inputs, all analog (RF, composite, s-video, and component)

Comment: @Keltari - ahhh, potentially the worst of both worlds? Are there any adjustments available on the LCD?

Comment: @JonCuster I havent messed with it too much.  Switching channels was a massive improvement.  However, when the composite adapter arrives, Ill just use that.  I would assume that will solve the issue.  It was just that the RF modulator was all I had.

Comment: The composite adapter came in and the picture looks great.  It was definitely the RF modulator that was producing the fuzziness.  I guess now that I have a good connection, I will open up the modulator.  I wont feel as bad if I break it.  I will post an answer once I open it and see whats inside.

Comment: Please be aware that video sent over RF is bandwidth-limited and _will_ make screens fuzzy. This is a technical limit you cannot avoid. Would you mind to add an image to your question for us to see? It was and still is the best to connect the video signal directly.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the specifics of the TI 99's modulator makes things especially un-fun to get a good picture out of. Since the modulator and the switch box are all in one unit (other devices it's usually two discrete components typically with the modulator inside the main device) you're denied one of the easiest ways to improve RF picture quality, namely don't use a switch box at all instead connecting the RF output directly to the coaxial antenna input on the TV with a passive adapter. You could modify the TI 99s modulator to bypass the switch, but I suspect it's non-trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not directly answering my own question, this is the solution I ended up doing:

I just ended up buying a composite adapter, which works great.  I decided against opening up the RF modulator, as I dont want to damage it.  While I can fix various electronic problems, I am not an electrical engineer and I do not want to damage the modulator visually or electrically.  Other than being a little fuzzy, it works.  Since I dont plan on using it, why risk breaking it?  I dont think its worth it.  If I ever end up selling the TI-99/4a, the next owner can decide what to do with it.